# converting java method to jQuery function

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have to make compatible the java function with jQuery. The jQuery [Real Person captcha](http://keith-wood.name/realPersonRef.html) validate function is written by java. I want to validate the captcha in jQuery. So, I tried to write the java function in jQuery. But the function could not return the right value.

**Java:**

```
private String rpHash(String value) { 
   int hash = 5381; 
   value = value.toUpperCase(); 
   for(int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) { 
     hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + value.charAt(i); 
   } 
   return String.valueOf(hash); 
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
function rpHash(value) { 
  hash = 5381; 
  value = value.toUpperCase(); 
  for($i = 0; $i < value.length; $i++) { 
    hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + value.charAt($i); 
  } 
  return hash; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd help if you'd post the expected result (from Java) and the actual result (from JavaScript). I tested it with the string `"abc"` and the Java function returns `193450027` while the JavaScript version returns `"00177573ABC"`. Looking at these results, the problem is much easier to spot.

The problem is that you did not translate the loop body correctly. `hash` is an `int`, thus `((hash << 5) + hash)` is also an `int`. However, `value.charAt(i)` is a **`char`**. What happens when Java needs to add an `int` to a `char`? Simple: a `char` is a Unicode character represented by two bytes. The `char` is extended to an `int` with the same Unicode value and is then added to the `int`.

However, JavaScript works very differently. `hash`  is a `number` and `value.charAt(i)` is a `string` with one character. When adding a `number` to a `string`, the `+` is interpreted as a **concatenation** of two `string`s and thus the result is also a `string`. Since JavaScript is not statically typed, it is perfectly legal for the value of `hash` to change from `number` to `string`.

In further iterations, `hash` will (most likely) be a `string` holding both numerical and non-numerical characters. Thus, when evaluating `hash << 5`, the implicit conversion from a `string` to a `number` needed for the shifting operation silently fails and returns `0`. The `+ hash` as well as `+ value.charAt($i)` become concatenations for the same reason as above.

Therefore, the correct translation would be to retrieve the **character code** rather than the *character*:

```
hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + value.charCodeAt($i);
```

This will correctly result in the intended addition of two `number`s.

On an unrelated note, you should write `var $i = 0` instead of `$i = 0` in your for initialization to prevent leaking `$i` to the global scope. The same applies to `hash`, which should be declared as `var hash = 5381`. Also, the convention is that variables prefixed with `$` represent a jQuery object, which `$i` doesn't. You better just name it `i` like in Java.

Comment: Thanks. It works. And your explanation is awesome. Thanks once agin.